# an obvious invariant fails in Dafny

Tags: verification, dafny

```
  datatype CACHE_STATE = I| S| E
  datatype MSG_CMD = Empty| ReqS| ReqE| Inv| InvAck| GntS| GntE
  type NODE=nat
  type DATA=nat
type boolean=bool

class  class_0  {
var 
Data : DATA,
Cmd : MSG_CMD
}


class  class_1  {
var 
Data : DATA,
State : CACHE_STATE
}





method n_RecvGntSinv__1_2( 
Chan2 : array<class_0 > , 
Cache : array<class_1 > ,i:nat, N1:nat ,p__Inv0:nat,p__Inv2:nat)
modifies Chan2[i]
modifies Cache[i]
requires 0<= i<N1

requires Cache.Length ==N1
requires N1>0

requires Chan2.Length ==N1


requires p__Inv0!=p__Inv2&&p__Inv2<N1&& p__Inv0<N1

requires Chan2[i] != null
requires Cache[i] !=null

requires i!=p__Inv0&&i!=p__Inv2
requires (!((Cache[p__Inv2].State == E) && (!(Cache[p__Inv0].State == I)))) 
requires   (Chan2[i].Cmd == GntS)



 ensures Cache==old(Cache)
 ensures Chan2==old(Chan2)

ensures   (!((Cache[p__Inv2].State == E) && (!(Cache[p__Inv0].State == I))))

{
  Cache[i].State := S;
  Cache[i].Data := Chan2[i].Data;
  Chan2[i].Cmd := Empty;
}
```

I have placed the requirement i is different from p__Inv2 and p_Inv0, thus the assignments should not disturb the evaluation of the invariant.

It is obvious that the invariant (!((Cache[p__Inv2].State == E) && (!(Cache[p__Inv0].State == I)))) should hold if it holds before execution.

Dafny shows my assertions fail and gives a counterexample I cann't understand.

Comment: By my understanding, Cache[i] is still a reference(pointer)  if Cache[i] is of a class type.

Answer (score 0):

Your precondition allows the possibility that `Cache[i]` references the same object as `Cache[p__Inv0]` or `Cache[p__Inv2]`. If that's what you intended, then the method body is indeed incorrect, as reported by the verifier. If that's not what you intended, then a precondition like

```
requires forall j,k :: 0 <= j < k < Cache.Length ==> Cache[j] != Cache[k]
```

will make your method verify.